# Why does Selenium uses a lot of memory

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, memory, geckodriver

I want to know selenium with firefox question，
I used Firefox version 56.0.2,selenium3.5.1,and geckodriver 0.19.1,server ubuntu(x64) os,firefox --headless mode
I find when I run my app for a long time, the firefox memory will increase a lot, such 400MB or more, and when I let firefox open `about:blank`, the memory don not decrease
I want to know how to decrease the firefox memory (do not kill the firefox process), only use the selenium to control firefox or start firefox with some config
I want to open "about:blank" or other URL to reduce memory,but I find it doesn't work;

Answer (score 4):

**No**,*Selenium* itself doesn't uses any memory. It's the *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* processes which consumes the memory. For an example when you create a new instance of any *WebDriver* variant to start a relevant *Web Browsing Session*, both the process consumes memory.

Now the different *Browser Client* variants will follow different and distinct methods and style to `initiate`, `manage` and `teardown` the browser internal process. So memory consumption will be different for the different browsers.

Answering your questions :

- *When I run my app for a long time, the firefox memory will increase a lot* : In-coarse of handling a active browsing session, the browser binary have to keep track a lot of memory ([stack memory / heap memory](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/stack-heap.htm)) resources time to time. Hence memory consumption can go up/down depending on situation.
- *I want to know how to decrease the firefox memory* : No, you have no control over the memory consumption of a browser.

### Solution

*Web Browsers* have evolved a lot recently. Each of the *Web Browser* variants e.g. *Mozilla*, *Chrome* and *Internet Explorer* are continuously working on a more momery efficient browser process. You can take the following steps for your *Automated Tests* to consume the optimum memory :

- Keep the [*JDK Version*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) updated to the latest versions as each release aims towards optimum memory utilization.
- Keep the [*Selenium Version*](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) updated to the latest versions as each release aims towards better memory management.
- Keep the [*WebDriver Version*](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) updated to the latest versions as each release aims towards better memory management.
- Keep the *Web Browser Version* updated to the latest versions as each release aims towards better memory utilization.
- If the base version of your *Web Browser* is too older, you may consider to uninstall the *Web Browser* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent *stable* and *GA* version of the *Web Browser* .
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool before and after your *Test Execution* to wipe off the OS system chores.
- Perform the *Test Execution* in an isolated system free from *Manual Intervention*
- Keep the *Test System* within the *Test Lab* well equipped with the *Hardware Requirements* to execute the *Test Suites*.

Comment: I want to know when i use Selenium to open many urls,such as faceook,google or more;     at last ,I open  about:config the page,I found the firefox memory doesn't reduce,i feel that the page is blank,the memory should be reduced,but it doen't work ,why?

Comment: @tjxy573 As an user we don't have a control over how memory handling is carried out by the _OS_ and _Browser Binary_ combination.So IMO, there is no point in validating/observing memory stats until and unless it is part of your _Tests_ . But if you have a valid point/observation you can raise the issue with the _Browser Vendors_ and you may be rewarded too.

Comment: at last,I resolve the question by myself, actually this is bug of firefox  for long long time,so I do not use firefox,I  used chrome,and I found the memory of chrome is smaller than firefox ,especially in headless,and very stable；I can use 1G memory can run my app,but is will cost 2G if I use firefox;than you!

Comment: Too much buzzwords, too little to no meaning. The bullets under "solution" are all devoid of meaning and/or outright false.