# Is my cpu usage normal while using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cpu-usage

My cpu usage is on average 17% with peaks of 22% when running this selenium script. Is this normal? I have a 5 5600g processor and am not running anything in the background. Thanks in advance.

```
Button = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")
while not (driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")):
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.refresh()
Button[0].click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially there is no benchmarking about *CPU* usage while executing test using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491).

Hence, I won't be suprised with ***CPU*** usage on average as **17%** with peaks of **22%** even with 5 5600g processor as historically:

- [Why does Selenium uses a lot of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535346/why-does-selenium-uses-a-lot-of-memory/48536579#48536579)
- [chromedriver.exe runs ~8 chrome.exe instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519290/chromedriver-exe-runs-8-chrome-exe-instances/58521183#58521183)
- [Many process of Google Chrome (32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466)
- [How to quit all the Firefox processes which gets initiated through GeckoDriver and Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830622/how-to-quit-all-the-firefox-processes-which-gets-initiated-through-geckodriver-a/58833151#58833151)

and the remediation steps are mentioned in:

- [Limit chrome headless CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811)
- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-junit-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-cal/48003289#48003289)